# SwiftUI - update view after adding CoreData record

Tags: swiftui, nsfetchrequest

When a user wants to create a new record, I'd like to a) go to a new view, b) create the record during `.onAppear`, and then c) have the view update using the newly created record.

The first part is easy. I have a `NavigationLink` that goes to the new view along with the user name as a property. And I can create a new record during `.onAppear`. But it's the last part where things get tricky.

I have tried to create the record and switch views with a simultaneous gesture, I've tried loading the new view with a toggle view function, and about a dozen less inspired ideas. The problem always comes down to this: **How do I get the FetchRequest to update after the new record has been created?** Note: I need a reference to the newly created record so that the user can add things to the record.

Here's the code so far...

```
struct RecordView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    let appDelegte = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    var fetchedRecords: FetchRequest<Record>
    var currentUser: User
    
    init(recordNumber: String) {
        fetchedRecords = FetchRequest<Record>(entity: Record.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "user.recordNumber = %@", recordNumberNumber))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(fetchedRecords.wrappedValue.first.recordNumber)
        
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.CreateNewRecord()
    }
    
    func CreateNewRecord() {
        let newRecord = Record(context: self.moc)
        newRecord.id = UUID()
        let recordNumber = "AABBCCDDEE"
        
        user.addToRecords(newRecord)
        appDelegate.saveContext()

    //This is when the fetched request should fetch the new record and the Text view should be updated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked was combining a NavigationLink with a Button as explained by @kontiki. That allowed me to create a new record *before* going to the new view.I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it definitely works! The code below shows the theory behind the solution.

```
@State private var presentMe = false
@State var currentNumber = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(number: currentNumber), isActive: $presentMe) { EmptyView() }
                
                Button(action: {
                //This is where I created a new record and saved to Core Data
                    self.currentNumber = 5 
                    //I was then able to pass the new record to the second view through the navigation link
                    self.presentMe = true
                }) {
                    Text("Go to SecondView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("The number is now = \(number)") //The number is now = 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about the bit where you say you want to create a record onAppear whilst a user created a record? Anyways I would probably create a variable for the text and have it set to the new record inside the onAppear function. Although the whole onAppear create record still confuses me and might make the implementation of the variable more difficult.

Comment: What I should have said is, "When a user wants to create a new record..." In other words, it hasn't happened yet. A variable would work great if I didn't need a reference to the newly created record. Welcome to stack overflow!